# Unable to install ACL

Tags: server, apt, software-installation, repository, acl

I am unable to install ACL on my Ubuntu 14.10 server (see output).

```
david@server:/mnt/storagedata$ sudo apt-get install acl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed
  acl
0 to upgrade, 1 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
Need to get 0 B/43.8 kB of archives.
After this operation, 197 kB of additional disk space will be used.

david@server:/mnt/storagedata$ setfacl
The program 'setfacl' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install acl
david@server:/mnt/storagedata$
```

As you can see the command does not install ACL.

Extra info:

```
david@server:/mnt/storagedata$ sudo uname -a
Linux server 3.16.0-43-generic #58~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jun 22 10:21:20 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

How do I install ACL?

Comment: Did you actually install it? Did you enter `y`? Try this way `sudo apt-get install -y acl`.

Comment: I didn't get asked to enter Y or N at the end. This is all the output I got from running the command. Adding the -y flag gives the same result

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `apt-cache policy acl`. Fixed a typo.